# Is there a way to change html element on hovering on it in ASP.Net page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net

The tempdata populates a div in the aspx page.
Whenever the parent div - SomeClassParent is being hovered on, the child span text - SomeClassChild3 string should be shown.
How do I achieve that with jQuery?

Below is the js portion of the code

```
function ShowDiv(Somedata){
 for(var v in Somedata){
    var tempdata = ''
    tempdata += '<div class="SomeClassParent">'
    tempdata += '<div class="SomeClassChild">'+Somedata[v].serialnum+'</div>'
    tempdata += '<span class="SomeClassChild2">'+Somedata[v].textdata.slice(0,49).trim()+'</span>'
    tempdata += '<span class="SomeClassChild3" style="display:none;">'+Somedata[v].textdata.slice(49,v.textdata.length).trim()+'</span>'
    tempdata += '</div>'
}
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.SomeClassParent').hover(function () {
        $(".SomeClassChild3").css({"display":"block"});
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want these to collapse when *not* hovering over them.  So, you'll need to use mouseenter and mouseleave versus just hover.

You'll also want to find the parent's children, not the blanket class "SomeClassChild3" or all elements with that class will display when you hover over anything with the class "SomeClassParent"

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.SomeClassParent').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find(".SomeClassChild3").css({"display":"block"});
    });
    $('.SomeClassParent').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find(".SomeClassChild3").css({"display":"none"});
    });
});
```

```css
.SomeClassParent{
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="SomeClassParent">
  <div class="SomeClassChild">Child</div>
  <span class="SomeClassChild2">Child2</span>
  <span class="SomeClassChild3" style="display:none;">Child3</span>
</div>

<div class="SomeClassParent">
  <div class="SomeClassChild">Child</div>
  <span class="SomeClassChild2">Child2</span>
  <span class="SomeClassChild3" style="display:none;">Child3</span>
</div>

<div class="SomeClassParent">
  <div class="SomeClassChild">Child</div>
  <span class="SomeClassChild2">Child2</span>
  <span class="SomeClassChild3" style="display:none;">Child3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry to spoil the three 9's you had, but hey, now you got more privileges https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: When i run the code in the ASP environment, it doesnt recognize the find - doesn't do anything. Is there any alternative route ?

Comment: Well, that probably means you aren't using JQuery.  Do you get errors using $(this) ?